# XUbuntu 20.04 LTS with xorg - fonts problem

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, xorg, fonts

I'm having trouble displaying my fonts.

My system is a XUbuntu 20.04 LTS with lightdm and XServer (xorg modesetting) with its own Labview application. Without gnome. The Xserver uses the bitmap fonts.

I use xfontsel to test the fonts and the fonts are not clean here either. So some letters are thicker than the others. (See photo). >> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAQls.png)

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: FYI:  You're aware that Xubuntu 20.04 LTS was a *flavor* of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and came with 3 years of supported life (refer https://xubuntu.org/news/xubuntu-20-04-released/ where you'll read "*a long-term support (LTS) release and will be supported for 3 years, until April 2023.*" with 5 years applying to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu base but not *flavors*. You're still on-topic here with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS questions though (*even if using Xfce*)